# Using vim as default editor for matlab

Tags: matlab, vim

I want to use gvim as the standard editor for Matlab. It used to work on Linux but now I am forced to use windows and I can't seem to figure out how to set the editor such that files are opened in gvim in a new tab.

In the preferences there is a field which allows to pass a command that points to the prefered text editor. That works, but things fail when I try to give additional options, in my case that would be "--remote-tab-silent" to tell gvim to open the file in a running instance in a new tab. More specifically, the following line in the matlab preferences works:

```
C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe
```

while this one fails

> C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent

A command line opens with the following error message (my own translation from German):

```
The command ""C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent"" is either spelled incorrectly or could not be found.
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the additional quotes, I have no idea why the command is issued with quotes, even though in the field I put it without. The follwing commands work when typed into the command line directly:

```
"C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe"
C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent file.m
```

and this one fails:

```
"C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent file.m"
```

I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: It seems MATLAB opens the editor using `start` (since it opens a DOS box) passing the whole string as the program name. From a Windows developer's perspective, this is the logical thing to (how else would you capture `Program Files` without bothering the user with errors about spaces in the file name? Besides, editors are configured via GUI, right?). In a Linux mindset, this is a serious lack of customizability and The MathWorks is stupid for not having thought about command line parameters :) I feel your pain, I've Linuxified every aspect of my Windows 7; go with Ben's batch file hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a good way to hack around it through the MATLAB settings; it looks like MATLAB is stupidly expecting the text editor to take only file names as arguments.

I think your best option, is to create a .bat script that simply passes any arguments it receives on to Vim, inserting the `--remote-tab-silent`.

I.e. create a .bat file with these contents:

```
"C:\pathtovim\gvim.exe" --remote-tab-silent %*
```

Then set up your MATLAB preferences to invoke the .bat file rather than Vim.